# Dynamically Generate Multi-Dimensional Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build a multidimensional array dynamically. What I want is basically this (written out for simplicity):

```
b = 0

test = [[]]

test[b] << ["a", "b", "c"]
b += 1
test[b] << ["d", "e", "f"]
b += 1
test[b] << ["g", "h", "i"]
```

This gives me the error: NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass. I can make it work by setting up the array like

```
test = [[], [], []]
```

and it works fine, but in my actual usage, I won't know how many arrays will be needed beforehand. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for an index variable like you're using. Just append each array to your `test` array:

```
irb> test = []
  => []
irb> test << ["a", "b", "c"]
  => [["a", "b", "c"]]
irb> test << ["d", "e", "f"]
  => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
irb> test << ["g", "h", "i"]
  => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
irb> test
  => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the `<<` method, use `=` instead:

```
test[b] = ["a", "b", "c"]
b += 1
test[b] = ["d", "e", "f"]
b += 1
test[b] = ["g", "h", "i"]
```

Or better still:

```
test << ["a", "b", "c"]
test << ["d", "e", "f"]
test << ["g", "h", "i"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example if you know the size of array you are creating.
  @OneDArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        p_size=@OneDArray.size
        c_loop=p_size/3
        puts "c_loop is #{c_loop}"
        left=p_size-c_loop*3

```
@TwoDArray=[[],[],[]]
k=0
for j in 0..c_loop-1
       puts "k is  #{k} "
        for i in 0..2
         @TwoDArray[j][i]=@OneDArray[k]
      k+=1
    end
 end
```

result will be @TwoDArray= [[1,2,3].[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]